# Use noun form of a word as a verb

Tags: grammar

I was wondering if I could use the noun form of a word as a verb. For example,
"I have to summary my results before I go out today." The idea here is that one would identify the usage from context. 'have to' parlays into the form of the word.

Comment: *Verbing* nouns happens, though generally only ever in casual language.

Comment: I would not advise "verbing" *summary*.  There are a some words where it might make sense, but for *summary* everyone would think "This guy is too dumb to know he should say *summarize*."

Comment: @HotLicks I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not grammatical English. The only time you would be able to use the "noun" form as a verb is when the two are identical, but then you're actually using the verb form.

English has a lot of nouns that have been turned into verbs simply by using an aesthetically pleasing affix, often *-ize* or *-ify*. In this case, "summary" becomes "summarize". One peeve I've heard in recent years has been the creation of such verbs when another already exists.

On the ridiculous side of things, I was a member of a programming team that did both of these things. We were adding form validation that would highlight incorrect fields pink. After implementing this for a form, we would say that we had "pinkified" the form. Similarly, we were discarding the old gray look and making the forms a light blue. After doing that, we would say we had "blue-ized" the form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well that makes sense with respect to the rules of grammar, but would it be appropriate to do so, say if I wrote a nontechnical document? Would someone read my essay and go, "this person does not know how the language"?

Comment: The standards of written language tend to be higher than spoken language. It _might_ be excused of a non-native speaker, particularly when spoken. Nonetheless, strive to write as grammatically correct as possible with the extra time granted for the written word.